# Can't install tidyverse in Mac Terminal

Tags: r, tidyverse

It appears I have all of the dependencies that compose tidyverse, such as dplyr, purr, broom, stringr, etc.. When I check my .installedpackages() tidyverse isn't there, And when I try to install.packages("tidyverse") it isn't added to my list of packages, I get this output:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4d/rw_b0kln1g127gn9mc5905t00000gn/T/RtmpMIaOnB/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘ps’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘systemfonts’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘processx’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘textshaping’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
8: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am able to install other packages and they are added right away, though I am having a hard time installing the tidyverse package, which is all I need. I have tried through the terminal as well and the outcome is similar to the console in RStudio.

```
.libPaths() #output in Rstudio console
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library"       "/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.1/lib/R/library"
```

Do I have to explicitly define a path for my R packages? These are the 2 that pop up when I type `.libPaths()`.
When `install.packages("tidyverse")` wasn't working in the console I tried:
`install.packages("tidyverse", lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library")` and it's the same result.

All my packages, homebrew, rstudio, are up to date. I have restarted my Rstudio session and still nothing.

I even tried uninstalling the packages that compose tidyverse:

```
remove.packages(c("ggplot2", "dplyr", "tidyr", "readr", "purrr", "tibble", "stringr", "forcats"))
install.packages(c("ggplot2", "dplyr", "tidyr", "readr", "purrr", "tibble", "stringr", "forcats"))
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

As well as this:

```
install.packages("tidyverse", type = "binary")
```

And nothing seems to be working, if there is any way someone could help me I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: as i mentioned at the end of the question I have tried uninstalling the packages that compose tidyverse:

remove.packages(c("ggplot2", "dplyr", "tidyr", "readr", "purrr", "tibble", "stringr", "forcats")) install.packages(c("ggplot2", "dplyr", "tidyr", "readr", "purrr", "tibble", "stringr", "forcats")) install.packages("tidyverse")

As well as this: install.packages("tidyverse", type = "binary")

Comment: You used `brew` to install r?

Comment: Yee I used brew to install R. I tried the same thing in the terminal as well removing the packages and reinstalling. I verified they were removed with installed.packages() and didn't see them. I install.packages('tidyverse') afterwards in terminal and I see the dependencies now, but still don't see tidyverse in my installedpackages() for some odd reason. This is my terminal output when i try to load the library...> library(tidyverse)
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’

Comment: Do **not** use Homebrew to install R, it only causes trouble. Install R from the official source at https://r-project.org, or use [Rig](https://github.com/r-lib/rig) to install it, if you need more control.

Comment: Thank you!! I unistalled R/Rscript in the terminal, redownloaded R through https://cran.r-project.org/, and now I finally have access to the tidyverse package. I think using homebrew to install R was what initially caused my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially try to install `tidyverse` using this?

```
# install.packages("pak")
pak::pak("tidyverse/tidyverse")
```

[Tidyverse GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse)

Otherwise I think we might need some more context, to see what the problem is.

Comment: I fully support using ‘pak’ but it won’t solve OP’s issue.

Comment: I see, I think pak sometimes some helpful traceback. This could potentially help identifying the actual problem. Because the output given is kind of minimal, as I have encountered similar output, but often if you scroll up, you can see either suggestions during installation, e.g. install other packages through brew. So I guess we would need more context.

Answer (score -2):

my suggestion would be to try the following within your RStudio:

```
install.packages("BiocManager", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
BiocManager::install("tidyverse")
```

if that doesn't work i would recommend to reinstall R following these guidelines:
https://cran.r-project.org/

And then try BiocManager again, it is the safest way of installing R packages

Comment: There’s absolutely no reason to pull ‘BiocManager’ into this.

Comment: I experienced biocmanager is usually more successful in installing dependencies, hence my suggestion. Although perhpas here the main problem is not having installed R via CRAN and instead via homebrew